# How to keep an image outside of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a maze game, and I want the walls for the game to be impassable. There is an image following my cursor, and I was wondering what element would be best for what I am doing. I have tried a div, but it is really difficult to get that to work. I don't want the image to be able to enter the element at all. What is the easiest way to make an image stay out of an element? I prefer jQuery, but I am flexible with pure js.

code:

```js
    var startMove;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var DIFF_SNAP = 10;
  var DIFF_UNSNAP = 100;
  var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
  var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
  if (!startMove && Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_SNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_SNAP) {
    startMove = true;
    $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
  } else if (startMove && !(Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_UNSNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_UNSNAP)) {
    startMove = false;
  }
  if (startMove) {
    $("#image").css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
  } else {
    $('html').addClass('showCursor');
  }
});

$(document).mouseleave(function() {
  startMove = false;
})

$("#drop").mouseenter(function(){
 if(startMove)
   alert("Success");
});
```

```css
    html {cursor: none;}
html.showCursor{cursor: default;}
#image{
position:absolute;
width:25px;
z-index: 100;
height:auto;
}

#drop{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:aqua;
  position: absolute;
  left:200px;
  top: 300px;
  z-index:99
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/mac-osx-arrow-cursor.png"/>

<div id="drop">
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3x7cgLdr/27/

It is prefered that you add a jsfiddle to your solution, so I can work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this collision checking :

```
function collisionCheck(ax,ay) {
        var collide = true;

        var aminY = ay;
        var aminX = ax;
        var amaxX = aminX + $('#image').width();
        var amaxY = aminY + $('#image').height();

        $('.maze').each(function(){

            collide = true;

            var bminY = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            var bminX = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft(); 
            var bmaxX = bminX + $(this).width();
            var bmaxY = bminY + $(this).height();

            if (amaxX < bminX) collide = false; // a is left of b
            if (aminX > bmaxX) collide = false; // a is right of b
            if (amaxY < bminY) collide = false; // a is above b
            if (aminY > bmaxY) collide = false; // a is below b

            if (collide) {
                return collide;
            }
        });
      return collide;
    }
```

JSFiddle : [Collision Check](https://jsfiddle.net/8pc3u7t9/)

Comment: could you please use another element instead of a div?

Comment: I don't want to use a div, but instead another element.

Comment: @RandomChannel it will work on another element just use class `maze` to the element.

Comment: @RandomChannel here is another example using another element : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8pc3u7t9/1/)

Comment: Cool! that works, now I want to apply the jQuery from this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3x7cgLdr/27/)